# Pedidos maior que 30 dias

Tags: sql

boa tarde.

Estou montando um relatório na qual preciso informar em uma coluna, os produtos que não tiveram movimentação por mais de 30 dias. A campo que utilizo é de padrão DATETIME. Toda vez que é inserida alguma informação de movimentação, é adicionado dia e hora. Exemplo:

```
Produto A | OCORRÊNCIA | 01/06/2019 10:00:00
Produto A | OCORRÊNCIA | 01/06/2019 12:00:00
Produto A | OCORRÊNCIA | 01/06/2019 16:00:00

Produto A | OCORRÊNCIA | 10/07/2019 10:00:00
```

Neste caso eu precisaria informar que o produto A ficou mais de 30 dias sem movimentação. Não sei o que posso utilizar para verificar essa lógica, visto que tenho somente um campo que campo para fazer a manipulação. Tentei com HAVING mas não consegui.

Comment: Utilize a função de agregação MAX, juntamente com a cláusula GROUP BY produto, e na cláusula WHERE filtre apenas as datas máximas que sejam menores que a data atual - 30 dias.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT produto FROM movimentacao WHERE data < DATEADD(Day, -30, GETDATE());
```

Chutei os nomes das colunas e da tabela, mas a ideia é essa... e não sei qual banco de dados você tá usando, então a função de somar a data pode ser levemente diferente.

Comment: Opa, deu certo. Muito obrigado. Estava confundindo se iria precisar de outro campo data. Mas agora foi!